# How to add attributes to <li> for a particular menu item

Tags: wordpress, menu, wp-nav-walker

I am using Menu Description to add an image for a menu item with the following function

```
function call_desc_with_div( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    if ( !empty( $item->description ) ) {
       $item_output = '<img src="' . $item->description . '">';
       }
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'call_desc_with_div', 10, 4 );
```

However the HTMl markup comes like this

```
<li id="menu-item-12345" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12345"><img src="http://my-image.png"></li>
```

I want to add the image (be it just a background image or whatever) inside the `<li>` for that particular menu item. Something like this

```
<li id="menu-item-12345" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12345" style="background-image:url(http://my-image.png);"></li>
```

Any help will be appreciative. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the option is available in wordpress backend itself.You need to enable "css classes" from screen option

Comment: I think you have not read my question. With CSS class option I can add a class but how about adding an element in the <li> or adding inline css in the <li>?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can add an item description to that menu item in backend eg:desc and
check like this

```
$p = $item->description
if( $p =='desc') {
$output .= $indent . '<li class="class1">';
}else {
 $output .= $indent . '<li>';  
}
```